# How to extract all Github Secrets to server virtual enviroments?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

It would be nice to have one place where I have credentials, that I pass to virtual enviroments of my django app on self-hosted server. I think Github Secrets is good place. But I found that I have to define them few times. First time is in Github Secrets and after to Action like `SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}`.

Are any ways I don't define with the same name to Action? Something like `{{ **secrets.variables_names }}: ${{**secrets.variables_values}}`.

I understand, that I can do python script that can do something like that on server side, but this is not much better than manual defining of virtual envs. Can you give me good pattern how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent a malicious task or script from extracting all your secrets and playing havoc on your environment, the GitHub runner only passes secrets to a step in the workflow when they are passed explicitly.

There currently is no bulk statement that will automatically import all secrets into the scope of a workflow step. A python script on the server will also not work since there is no API to retrieve the GitHub Action Secrets without running a workflow.

> Note: GitHub Secrets aren't meant as a general purpose secret store for your applications. [Azure vault, hashicorp's vault, Windows Credential Store](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142264/storing-application-secrets-safely-on-linux) and many similar tools exist that do provide specific permissions on secrets and a better management solution.
>
> GitHub Actions Secrets are meant to hold the secrets that are needed to perform the actions of the workflow. After the workflow is finished, the application that you deployed shouldn't be reliant on GitHub Actions to make sure it has access to all the latest and correct values.

Comment: emm, looks a bit strange, honestly. If I want to pass manually all secrets to server enviroment means, that I am sure that they will not get any harm.

Bad news, mate, that I can't do mass passing to server. 

But thanks for your clearlifiyng :)

Comment: 't is what 't is.