# How to use .env file with Github Actions without autodeleting?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

In continuation of my previous question [How to extract all Github Secrets to server virtual enviroments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75637863/how-to-extract-all-github-secrets-to-server-virtual-enviroments), I found that even if I pass manually my local `.env` file to the web server, it is overwritten after my action is done. Are there any ways to save this file on the production server?

If not, are maybe any ways to mass move variables from this `.env` file to GitHub Secrets?

So, how can I move variables from the local `.env` file to the production server quickly?

This is my workflow config, if important https://pastebin.com/qx2XGwfk

Comment: We need some clarification. You talk about your "webserver" and "production server", what are they? What is overwriting your .env file? If this is a Github Action, it might help to show us your workflow. **Note:** .env files are not intended or production, secrets on disk can be stolen. Instead, [your configuration should live in environment variables](https://12factor.net/config) where they cannot be stolen. This is why Github Secrets prevents what you're trying to do. You could try something like [dotenv.org](https://www.dotenv.org/docs/integrations/github-actions/nextjs.html).

Comment: Webserver and production server are the same — my ubuntu vps on hosting provider. I only use another words to prevent a tautology. 

.env file that is not part of repository and that I add manually to server from filezilla is been deleting after runner. And if I understand correct, before checkout of branch, because I have errors of not existing enviroment variables in project

About Github Secrets — I noted a problems in my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75637863/how-to-extract-all-github-secrets-to-server-virtual-enviroments

This is config pastebin.com/qx2XGwfk

Comment: Github Actions should not be doing anything to your production server that you did not ask it to. We'd need to see your workflow file to advise. And again, there are existing services such as [dotenv.org](https://dotenv.org) and [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/use-cases/secrets-management) which solve your problem.

Comment: I already sent config, but ok, sending one more time https://pastebin.com/qx2XGwfk. I don't know, mate. The .env file is deleting after a new run. I have already used python-dotenv in my requirements. Do you offer to user their cloud system? Do they have mass adding of enviroments from file?

Comment: Important information is likely to not be seen in the comments. Please [edit that into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75638519/edit) to ensure others see it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Checkout action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/checkout) is not intended for deployment. It will, by default, clean up an existing checkout. Since your .env file is not part of the repository, it will be deleted.

```
# Whether to execute `git clean -ffdx && git reset --hard HEAD` before fetching
    # Default: true
    clean: ''
```

You can turn this off by passing `clean: false`.

Once again, deploying your secrets in a file risks their being stolen if someone gains access to just your filesystem. Use [environment variables](https://12factor.net/config) or a secrets service instead; this adds an extra layer of security.

Comment: Oh, ok, nice. Thank you very much for clearlyfing. By the way, add to your example, please, that clean should be ander with: block to be more obvious. 

- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
       clean: false

And I would be glad to use enviroment variables, if I could add them enough quick to github or linux.